# How to avoid Ember tests failing if endpoint returns 404?

Tags: testing, ember.js, ember-data

**The Context:**

I have an ember app, which I just updated from 2.16 to 2.18.2 (latest from the 2.x versions).
I have a stubby server for testing purposes.

**The Problem**

When running my tests, some endpoints returns an 404 (which is expected), but my test fails with the following log:

```
not ok 36 Chrome 89.0 - [undefined ms] - Global error: Uncaught Error: Ember Data Request GET http://127.0.0.1:8882/stubby/patito/8 returned a 404
Payload (Empty Content-Type)
Not Found at http://localhost:9091/assets/vendor.js, line 54879
 After execution of test: Acceptance Student | Quizzes with metadata questions: Selection of 'practice quiz' option
    ---
        browser log: |
            testContext: [object Object]
            ERROR: Uncaught Error: Ember Data Request GET http://127.0.0.1:8882/stubby/patito/8 returned a 404
            Payload (Empty Content-Type)
            Not Found at http://localhost:9091/assets/vendor.js, line 54879
```

**What I have tried**

- I added mock endpoint to return some data. The problem here is adding too many and unnecessary data.
- By-passing those doing something like this:

```
// tests/test-helper.js
import Qunit from 'qunit';
import { setupOnerror } from '@ember/test-helpers';

Qunit.testStart(() => {
  setupOnerror(e => {
    if (e.message.includes('404')) return;
    // still throw all other errors
    throw e;
  });
});
```

Is there any possible way to flag those 404 as expected since they are not needed for a particular test to pass?
Also, Any clue about why having an 404 in an ajax call breaks a tests would be appreciated.

**Update**

My best guess at this point is that when I updated ember-data from 2.16.2 to 2.18.0, ember-data is trying to re-validate data (previously loaded from another endpoint).
Throwing an exception if this endpoint does not exist.

This behavior was not happening in ember-data 2.16.2.

Wondering now how to catch these type of exceptions:

[image: Uncaught error]

Comment: Ideally, a client-side test environment should not have server dependency. If we enable that dependency, the results will not be predictable. Try using some mocking techniques such as ember-cli-mirage to mock API requests and use some dummy data. That way, your tests will only need to test the UI and its functionality and not the dependencies.

Comment: Slightly less optimal approach might be to add a guard in your code like `if (config.environment === 'test') { ... }` and skip this request or do smt different like putting an item in the local storage which you can verify in your ember tests.

Comment: Hi @GokulKathirvel, yes. I am using mock data served on my local env using 'stubby' which I think acts kinda like ember-cli-mirage.